# How to modify a field value at theme/Views level?

Tags: views, i18n-l10n, entities

My content type has a [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) field which stores a website URL (e.g. 'site.com'). I use this field in various views and node templates.

My site is multi-language, and I know how to check the current language using the global $language.

Now I need to modify the link field value depending on the selected language. So output 'site-en.com' if visitor is viewing the site in English, 'site-de.com' if viewing in German etc.

I can't use manual field translation ([Entity Translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation)) because the field values are imported from XML using [Feeds](http://drupal.org/project/feeds), and there are hundreds of values.

So I wonder if there is a hook to programatically modify a field value before it is used by templates and Views module?

Or maybe there is a better way..?

Comment: Have you tried using hook_preprocess function in your template.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy /modules/field/theme/field.tpl.php to your theme folder and rename it to field--field-site-link.tpl.php (if field key of your field is field_site_link), edit template, see comment in file for avalable variables, or just override existings

Comment: I followed this - thanks. In the end I made a small module with a function that checks the current site language and does a rewrite if required. Then I pass the content of the field to this function in field--field-site-link.tpl.php